# How to keep footer at the bottom with background at 100%?

Tags: css, html, background, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to figure out how to add a footer at the bottom of my webpage but it doesn't seem to "stick" at the bottom, I don't know if it's my background image at 100% that is causing the problem, so I kind of need help here keeping the footer at the bottom, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stick a footer at the very bottom of the document no matter what, then you can use `position:absolute` & `bottom:0px`. A background image shouldn't effect it's positioning.

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9zjg/)

And yes it would be helpful to see your current code that isn't working.